# How are packages.config paths resolved?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, nuget, xamarin-studio

I have a project with a packages.config file.  I do have a corresponding library.  When I attempt to build my solution in Visual Studio, it does find the library, and everything works.  But Xamarin Studio on my mac fails to find the same library.

For me, part of the problem is that I don't understand how the contents of the "packages" file corresponds to the path.  It's clearly not a direct correspondence.

Here is the packages.config file.  The relevant package is "splat".

**EDIT: the answer was apparently that I needed to restart my computer.  That said, it would still be interesting to know how it chooses the path.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="portable-net45+wp80+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Splat" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10" />
</packages>
```

And here is my packages directory in the finder:

```
WJ-macbook:packages william$ ls -RF

./Splat.1.2.1:
Splat.1.2.1.nupkg   lib/

./Splat.1.2.1/lib:
MonoMac/            monoandroid/
Net45/              monotouch/
NetCore45/          wp8/
Portable-Net45+WinRT45+WP8/

./Splat.1.2.1/lib/MonoMac:
Splat.dll   Splat.dll.mdb

./Splat.1.2.1/lib/Net45:
Splat.dll   Splat.pdb

./Splat.1.2.1/lib/NetCore45:
Splat.dll   Splat.pdb   Splat.pri

./Splat.1.2.1/lib/Portable-Net45+WinRT45+WP8:
Splat.dll   Splat.dll.mdb

./Splat.1.2.1/lib/monoandroid:
Splat.dll   Splat.dll.mdb

./Splat.1.2.1/lib/monotouch:
Splat.dll   Splat.dll.mdb

./Splat.1.2.1/lib/wp8:
Splat.dll   Splat.pdb
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows the NuGet installation process will actually modify the relevant project file to include a hint path for the packages.  Here is a line taken directly from one of my projects

```
<Reference Include="EditorUtils, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d1514c4742e0252, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\EditorUtils.1.3.0.0\lib\net40\EditorUtils.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The `HintPath` here is the method by which MsBuild discovers the EditorUtils reference.  This was added by NuGet during installation.

I do not know what the equivalent mechanism is on xamarin unfortunately although I imagine it's quite similar

Comment: Xamarin Studio works the same as Visual Studio since it uses MSBuild project files. A HintPath is set for the assembly and should point to the file in the packages directory.